Run Windows services on Intel P cores
I have a PC turned into home server, that I use for running self hosted builds for an Azure Pipeline. I have 3 build agents running on one PC. The PC/server has an Intel i7-12700f CPU with 8 P cores and 4 E cores. When I run a few Pipeline jobs the 4 E cores max out, but the P cores stay idle.
To create the services I just run the run.cmd downloaded from Azure.
If I disable the E cores in the BIOS, the services use the 8 P cores. But this way the power consumption of the PC goes up and I don't want to needlessly consume energy and release CO2.
I tried to set "Choose how to allocate processor resources." (in Settings, System, About. System info. Advanced sysyem settings. Advanced tab) to Background services, but that didn't have any effect on the core allocation.
The Windows power plan is balanced and I don't want to change it to High performance, because this PC is idle 99% of the time.
How do I get these three services to use only the P cores, and still have the E cores active?
